# Algorithm to generate a path in grid with specific number of cells to use

Tags: algorithm

I have a grid with a random size (for example 5 x 5 or 8 x 8 randomly generated) and also with a randomly generated start point and end point. Is there a possible way to know all possible paths that I can take from the start point to the end point with a specific number of cells to use and not go and check all possible moves (which will ramp up the complexity of the algorithm)?
So for example, this grid (S and E is start point and end point, and yeah, it is not really not required to start on one point than the other so maybe target points is the right word to use):

`0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  E  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  S  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0`

For example I need to use a total of 10 cells. So one solution will be:

`0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  E  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  |  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  |  -  |
0  0  0  0  0  S  0  |
0  0  0  0  0  |  0  |
0  0  0  0  0  -  -  |`

The last thing is that it must detect if a path can't be generated at all. For example in this grid, for some reason you can't generate a solution if the required cells to use is 10:

`0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  E  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  S  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you go multiple times on the same cell ? If so, detecting if no path exists is easy: find the shortest path. If it has the same parity as the paths you're looking for there are solution otherwise there aren't (assuming no diagonal move).

When some path exist, in order to find them all, a backtracking is the best option I can think of. You can prune branches when you are too far from the end (i.e the shortest path from where you are) compared to the remaining moves. With this, you should be close to an optimal solution as you continue moving only if a solution us still reachable (except for the last move before backtracking).

Finding the length of the shortest path is trivial: it's simply abs(x-xe) + abs(y-ye) (assuming no diagonal move again).

**Edit:**

Here is an implementation in python, assuming:
 - a `Position` class (storing `x` and `y` coordinates and providing equality comparison)
 - a `distance` (returning length of shortest path)
 - a `is_valid` function (returning false if a point is out of the map, could allow obstacles as well)
 - methods `right`, `left`, `up` and `down` (returning a modified `Position` object accordingly)

```
def find_path_rec(pos, target, remaining, path):
  if not is_valid(pos) or pos in path or distance(pos, target) > remaining:
    return []
  if pos == target:
    if remaining == 0:
      return [path + [pos]]
    else:
      return []
  path.append(pos)
  result = []
  for new_pos in [right(pos), left(pos), up(pos), down(pos)]:
    result.extend(find_path_rec(new_pos, target, remaining-1, path))
  path.remove(pos)
  return result
```

It works well on your example, returning 1016 paths for the first case and 0 for the second. Except the distance is considered as being 11 not 10 because it counts the number of moves including leaving E and reaching S. You can easily encapsulate it in another function for a more convenient use:

```
def find_path(pos, target, length):
  find_path_rec(pos, target, length+1, [])
```

Comment: Ooops. Forgot to mention that a cell can only be visited once. And no, not the shortest path, but all paths that uses 10 cells for example and only visits a cell once.

Comment: OK, it doesn't change much the backtracking solution (you just need to remember where you went already and avoid those cells). It just breaks the quick check to know if a solution exists (it still works and can save some time but will fail to identify some cases where no path exist, like a corridor of width 1)

Comment: Thanks! I think I get the gist of it, though I cannot try it now as I'm working with some other project. If you wouldn't mind, can you update it to add some simple pseudo code, but if not thanks anyway!

Comment: I can but that's ruining the fun part ! :-)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update. I guess you can say it won't be fun with that, so I think I will try to make my own implementation first and then compare it to yours so I'll learn and know my mistakes. Thanks!